# Deleting unnecessary symbols from variable in Jmeter

Tags: variables, jmeter, trim, symbols, beanshell

I have variable as string in this view:

```
["564546","56454654","3123123","868987"]
```

I need the script that deletes unnecessary symbols `[ ] "` and put it to another variable . (something like `trim` method)
I assume it should be made in BeanShell pre-processor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done via [Beanshell PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) as follows:

1. Add Beanshell PreProcessor as a child of the request which needs "another variable"
2. Put the following code into the PreProcessor's "Script" area:

   ```
   String yourvar = vars.get("yourvar");
   String anothervar = yourvar.replace("[","").replace("]","").replaceAll("\\\"","");
   vars.put("anothervar",anothervar);
   ```

Change "yourvar" and "anothervar" according to your variables reference names.

- `yourvar` - source variable name
- `anothervar` - result variable name

`vars` is a shorthand to [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance which provides access to JMeter variables in current context. See JavaDoc for the class for all available methods and [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for advanced information on Beanshell scripting in JMeter.